# Using a list index in a variable in python 3.3

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, indexing

I apologize in advance, I'm an absolute beginner. What I'm trying to do is have a for loop check user input against a list to see if it's contained in that list, and if it is, place the index of that list in a variable so it can be used to access an item in another list. Here is my code so far:

```
cust = ["Jim", "Jane", "John"]
bal = [300, 300, 300]

curCustIndex = ""
custName = input("What is your name?")
""" Let's assume the user chose "Jane" """

for i in cust:
    if custname == cust[i]:
        curCustIndex = i
```

Basically, what I want is for the `curCustIndex` to be set to an index, such as `[1]` for "Jane", so I can use it to correspond with an index in another list, such as the `bal` list. In this case, `bal[1]` would be the balance for "Jane." I've tried to search for an answer, but a lot of the related topics are a little too advanced for me understand. Oh, and yes, I'm intentionally using global variables. This is a beginner's python class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, and what is your question exactly?

Comment: What if there are two people named 'Jane'?

Comment: Use a dictionary, not a pair of lists.

Comment: dawg, we haven't gone that far yet; it's an intro class and we just started using lists. I guess what I was asking is how to change the variable to an index so I can use it in functions. I apologize for the lack of appropriate vocabulary, I'm new to this so it's hard for me to articulate what I want. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `for i in cust`, use `for i in range(len(cust))`. That will give you the index. Simply using `for i in cust` will assign the actual item from your list to `i`, not the index of the item in the list.

Better yet, use `for i, customer in enumerate(cust)`. When you do that, `i` is the index, and `customer` is the actual item from the list.

```
for i, customer in enumerate(cust):
  if custname == customer:
    curCustIndex = i
```

Comment: @booboodingding if she doesn't want you using `enumerate`, you can try replacing the `for` line like I suggested in the first paragraph. That should also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Python [lists have an `index`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method that returns the position of a given item:

```
>>> cust = ["Jim", "Jane", "John"]
>>> bal = [300, 300, 300]
>>> cust.index("John")
2
>>> bal[cust.index("John")]
300
```

As stated in the doc, it is an "error [to call index] if there is no such item":

```
>>> cust.index("Paul")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'Paul' is not in list
```

So in real code you have to wrap that in a `try ... except ...` block:

```
cust = ["Jim", "Jane", "John"]
bal = [300, 300, 300]

custName = input("What is your name?")
try:
    print(custName, "has", bal[cust.index(custName)])
except ValueError:
    print("No such client:", custName)
```

And testing:

```
sh$ python3 t.py
What is your name?John
John has 300
sh$ python3 t.py
What is your name?Paul
No such client: Paul
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `zip` combines two lists into pairs of elements -- one in each pair taken from each list.

```
In [135]: zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
Out[135]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

So we can iterate over both `customers` and `balances` together.

```
In [136]: customers = ["Jim", "Jane", "Steve"]

In [137]: balances = [100, 987654, 31415]

In [138]: for person, balance in zip(customers, balances):
   .....:   if("J" in person):
   .....:     print("{0} has a balance of {1}".format(person, balance))
   .....: 
Jim has a balance of 100
Jane has a balance of 987654
```

However, you might consider using a different datatype, so you don't have to loop over all the balances. [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) let you look up values by a "key", as follows:

```
In [140]: accounts = {"Jim": 100, "Jane": 987654, "Steve": 31415}

In [141]: accounts["Steve"]
Out[141]: 31415
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The assignment is that I make a bankapp that uses the input of a user and set it to a variable. Then I would pass the "custName" variable to a function, such as a deposit(custName), then have it alter the "bal" list according to the index of custName assigned during the for loop.